# Why does this question have more upvotes than views?

Tags: discussion, voting, views

I recently saw this question :

[image]

It has five upvotes, but only 4 views?

It might that the OP or their friends tried to increase the number of votes of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841673/onclick-x-and-y-coordinates-on-imageview-get-changed-after-zoom).

Comment: I assume there's a vote from the review queue, not counting as a visit to the question... (or just that 2 accounts from same IP have voted). Maybe a moderator can have this level of details, but I think only devs really know what is counted as view.

Comment: Views are cached, so they don't update as quickly as quickly as the votes do

Comment: @psubsee2003 I have refresh it two time but it give same Result. After  1 mintue later The People are increase.

Comment: @Ironman cached server side. Refreshing has no affect on that

Comment: @psubsee2003 and also the question is all about `zooming ImageView` then why the other User give `Instant 5 Vote`.??

Comment: In the [tag:android] tag up votes come for free on anything that looks reasonable AND has an nice image ....

Comment: @rene I like this point.

Comment: @rene depending on the time of day, it may only need an image at all.

Comment: The view counter is conservative.  I think it pays attention to the IP address of the HTTP request, at least to prevent the user's own views to get the count to increase.  That a user from that neck of the woods gets a large number of votes, all posted within a few minutes with no further voting and seemingly all from the same IP address is not unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things to cover here, but first is the direct answer to your question - *Why does this question have more upvotes than views?*

The most likely explanation is the caching of the view counter.  Many of the non-critical elements on a Stack Overflow page are cached (server-side) for performance.  There is no need to see the real time vote counter, so to limit the database queries, the view counter is pre-fetched and only updated at predetermined intervals.  The fact that you kept refreshing the page and saw it update after a minute supports that point.

Other *potential* reasons that could also result in more votes (up or down) than views are autovotes due to specific flags and the review queues, although neither seems to be a likely factor here.

- When flagging as spam, an automatic downvote is added to the point.  So a deleted spam question could be seen by only 6 people (the 6 people who flagged it as spam), but it would have 12 downvotes.  Since we're talking about upvotes and not downvotes, we know this didn't contribute in this case.
- Review queues may come into play as well.  It has not been conclusive stated whether or not views from within the review queues count towards the view count, but it is possible they don't count.  However, it is not like this post went through any of the review queues that permit voting since the user has enough rep and posts to not be subjected to the First Posts review queue.

So that brings it back to caching as the likeliest explanation.

---

As for the view counter itself, unless something has changed in the last 6 years, you can find some explanation as to how it works  in [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated).  But the short of it is, if you are signed in, it uses the question and your user number as part of the counting mechanism to only count unique views within a short time period (if you aren't logged in, then it uses your IP address and the question number instead).

So in theory, a dozen anonymous users with the same IP address could visit a question in the same 15 minute window, and it would only count as 1 view.  But since anonymous users can't vote, it's not possible to have a single view counted but result in multiple votes.  Same goes with logged in users, since the user id is part of the view count throttling mechanism and a single user can only vote once.

---

Lastly, it seems your concern is based on potential voting fraud.  For those cases, follow the guidance I provided in [What do to with ultra-sophisticated voting ring?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222412/what-do-to-with-ultra-sophisticated-voting-ring/222414#222414) rather than bringing your suspicions to meta.  It is possible that it is completely innocent and a false accusation could cause negative attention to an innocent user.