# Should the system invalidate all votes between two people on the same IP address?

Tags: feature-request, voting, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I know this will be a controversial suggestion, due to the side effects it will have, but I feel that it's time to have a discussion about this. Should the system automatically invalidate any vote cast by one user to another on their same IP address?

Everyone on Meta always seems to regard sock puppet operators or voting ring participants as some kind of master criminals, but in truth they are the absolute laziest people I have ever seen. Over the years, I have suspended hundreds if not thousands of people for voting fraud, and deleted way more sock puppets. In my experience, 99% of these puppets and 90+% of voting ring participants come from the same outward-facing IP address as their target. Many puppet operators don't even bother to give their accounts different names from their main account.

The number of people using Tor or even a different dynamic IP address for their puppets is vanishingly small. Most voting fraud is motivated by a desire to evade question bans, as can be seen by the fact that most of these people hit a question ban before employing a puppet to vote for them. Similarly, companies are training their employees to form voting rings so that they can inundate the site with questions in order to farm out their work. All of these people do the bare minimum amount of work in running these puppets and rings, and don't bother to hide their origin.

I don't care about fraudulent unicorn points that people are accumulating, but I do care about inflating votes on bad questions and answers and people evading question bans to dump trash on the site. Seeing stuff like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338442/should-we-be-flagging-when-we-think-theres-vote-manipulation-is-it-okay-to-hav) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338571/why-does-this-question-have-more-upvotes-than-views) (as but two recent examples) be inflated by voting rings is incredibly irritating to me and to other regular members of the site.

The current vote invalidation system is extremely conservative, only chasing after rapid bursts of votes. It is trivial to work around, and only catches a small fraction of puppets and voting rings. The majority are hunted down and dealt with manually by moderators.

Therefore, I suggest tightening this system to invalidate *any* votes cast between one user on an IP address and another user on that same IP address (using the last active IP address for both at time of voting). This could be done when the script runs overnight. Doing so would immediately eliminate almost all voting fraud on the site, and I think it would have a dramatic impact in many areas. For example, at one point 30% of the top askers in the last 30 days in [android] got there via fraud (in a sweep through these yesterday, that number was "only" 15%).

Now, this will have some noticeable side effects for areas where a large number of people share a public IP address, such as in large companies or in certain countries. Coworkers who honestly come across a post by a legitimate expert at their company and vote for it based on quality will have that vote invalidated. How frequently this happens is unknown. An argument could be made that odds are anyone at your IP address at the time you're voting is most likely someone you know, and good intentions or no, it's hard for you to be impartial about their content.

Maybe a low threshold could be placed, such as only triggering the invalidation after the second one cast between two users on the same IP address. This would allow for incidental, one-time voting between coworkers while blocking larger-scale coordination.

I'm asking this on Meta.SO, because from talking with other site moderators, no other site experiences voting fraud at anywhere near the frequency we do. People don't depend on other sites to do their job like they do here, and that leads to desperate behavior you don't see elsewhere. These measures may only need to apply to this site, and not others in the network.

Implementing this would eliminate almost all voting fraud overnight. Because most voting fraud is related to question ban evasion, it would also put a dent in that problem as well. Fewer bad questions would be asked by people now unable to evade questions bans, companies and school groups wouldn't be able to coordinate votes for wrong answers and bad questions, and moderators wouldn't have to invest so much time in tracking down sock puppets and voting rings.

Comment: I don't have a fully formed "answer", but at first pass, I think this is a good idea. I like the idea of eliminating a bunch of this fraud. Hopefully it helps to improve quality too, because users realize much faster that there isn't anything to gain. However, I think it's important to know a bit about the impact for those that would be unintentionally affected (large companies, universities, certain countries). I think those (and especially the universities) are where there will be a much higher risk of the incidental voting.

Comment: Do you think there is any way to determine roughly how many legitimate votes might be invalidated as a side-effect?

Comment: @Andy Not only big companies, universities - but there could potentially be overlap by stopping at a same hotel, or office.  IP crosses happen in odd ways and all of those ways could be impacted by an out-right invalidation of votes based on an IP cross.

Comment: For another potential reason for increased voter fraud on Stack Overflow, one needs only look at Stack Overflow Jobs; there's a real monetary advantage to increasing your rep.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - With database access, staff might be able to run a query to see how many votes in the last 30 days match these restrictions. That would only give a total of votes, though. You could compare that to the votes invalidated or removed due to deleted accounts in the same period, but those are only the rings and puppets bad enough for us to step in on and that SE staff have responded to invalidation requests on (there's a queue of these awaiting review). I don't even know an order of magnitude here.

Comment: There are also internet cafes to consider, housing with free, shared, public wifi (my apartments offer this), restaurants that offer free wifi, _stores_ that offer it... There are a lot of places where I'm at that offer free wifi. If this were implemented, I might restrict my SO usage to just my internet at home. Even then, what if a visiting friend uses my wifi for SO usage and votes on something without knowing the account was mine? (That last one is incredibly unlikely- I don't have many programmer friends, and none of them have an SO account currently. Or visit me at home.)

Comment: Regarding the stat mentioned about the android tag, do the matching IPs all occur within a small time window or are we talking about IPs that have matched at any point in time? If the time window is "small" (say the last several months), I'd feel comfortable with this. If it's any point in history, that gets a little messier. As Brad mentioned, these aren't criminal masterminds trying to build up years of history.

Comment: @Kendra - I'm not proposing this invalidate votes between you and anyone you could have ever cross-referenced IPs with, merely votes between two people "currently" at an IP address (with "currently" defined as the most recent access of both at the time the vote was cast). Your visiting friend would be hit by this, but not your accesses at a cafe, unless you and your target were there at the same time or quickly after one another.

Comment: @Andy - Small time window. Generally, matching within the last day or last few hours in the cases I dealt with yesterday. I'm not talking about long-term cross-refs here.

Comment: On the topic of SO vs other sites: yeah, I think that's a good call. Smaller sites don't have such a problem with mods spending time on vote fraud, and the collateral damage of removing actually-okay votes would hurt more.

Comment: To squash some of the concerns about coffee shops, hotels, ISP-dynamic-allocation, etc., we could implement a system that tracks how much 'churn' an IP has. If there's a high turnover of users seen at an IP, or simply a whole bunch of them with relatively little in common (think active in iOS v. PHP), this could be tuned dynamically to be less aggressive on those addresses.

Comment: @BradLarson Which can still happen, and does not help with other areas, such as the free housing wifi I mentioned. As I said, there are _a lot_ of places here that offer free wifi, and it's a large enough area with a lot of programming jobs around (from my last check) that it's completely feasible for two programmers who have never met to be using the same public wifi at the same public location at around the same time. I would think that risk would get higher the bigger the city and the more programmers.

Comment: How accurate do you think an automatic system would be? "Wilt thou also destroy the righteous with the wicked?" - *The Bible*, Gen. 18:23; "Better that ten guilty persons escape than that one innocent suffer" - *Commentaries on the Laws of England*, William Blackstone.

Comment: This is going to be a very hard sell.  The company has very little incentive to solve this problem, they don't like complaints.  And this is going to produce a *lot* of complaints.  From everybody that voted fraudulently, for one, they all instantly turn into co-workers.  Looking for a global solution to what is a in practice a very localized problem isn't the right approach anyway.  Best outcome is for the company to take this by the horns themselves and flatly state that votes will no longer be accepted from *some* parts of the world.  Bam, 90% fixed.  Could happen.

Comment: So, as you mentioned, the one of the main purposes here is to prevent people from subverting the question ban.  How does this accomplish that?  If the votes are invalidated at the end of the day, someone who is post banned can create a puppet, upvote themselves, get enough points to post a question, then later in the day the votes are reversed and the ban re-imposed, but they still asked their question.  Rinse and repeat the next time they have a question.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That quote is applicable when you're talking about putting someone to death for murder.  You *really* don't want to do that for an innocent person.  I don't think that it holds for votes though.  I would *much* rather have one of my votes removed if it meant that 10 fraudulent votes would be caught instead.  Those fraudulent votes are largely going to be upvoting really low quality content.  That's probably the *single* most harmful type of vote that could be cast.  It's far more harmful for such a post to get a bad upvote than for me to upvote a good question one more time.

Comment: To follow up on my earlier comment, what if the post ban algorithm simply ignored the votes that we're considering invalidating here, but the actual votes were kept?  People could upvote themselves all they want and it wouldn't actually get them out of a post ban.  (Obviously this would require computing this more often than once a day, to avoid the problem mentioned in my earlier comment; I'm not sure if that would be possible.)  It's not ideal, but I can't see it having much in the way of negative side effects.

Comment: @Servy - You might be able to address that case with modifications to the ban algorithm: don't lift the ban until X days have passed after positive voting, etc. I guess I'm tired of seeing just what you describe, someone getting banned, immediately creating a puppet, and then using their old account to vote for the new one to ensure it never hits the ban (or vice versa). I'm also tired of seeing 4-5 person voting rings at certain companies with the express purpose of allowing all of their employees to keep dumping bad questions and never getting banned. This is being taught in certain places.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm just as frustrated with all of those problems as you are.  I just want to make sure we actually solve the problem, rather than just make ourselves feel better about combatting them without actually slowing them down meaningfully.  In case it wasn't clear, I'd be 100% for something like this if it actually worked; it just might take some tweaks to this or other systems to make sure it actually works.

Comment: @Servy Those quotes apply to *any* punishment. OK, so the potential consequence of turning someone into a voting offender through unwarranted vote removal is unlikely to occur, but incremental offences against an innocent person can tip them over the edge into being a criminal or worse. And that would be only hyperbole if it didn't happen in real life.

Comment: Wouldn't doing this just drive people to instead using, for example, their mobile device to create/vote with the sock puppet? that'd just make it harder to catch the lazy ones, unless the ip addresses we use commonly are being stored with the account longer than the single session.

Comment: @AndrewMorton But it *doesn't* though.  In this case the person who has their votes reversed is almost certain to never even know that the votes were reversed, and as such won't have any reason to lash out at anyone.   That also isn't the primary point of the saying.  It's an ethical point, not about what that innocent person is going to go on to do.

Comment: @KevinB The theory is that enough of these people are sufficiently lazy that you bring the number of offenders down to a level that the mods can once again manage.  That's the theory at least.

Comment: @Servy I think it would also serve as a learning tool, immediately showing the user that voting fraud is being monitored. Very well could persuade a few to just not bother, rather than risking their account on something detectable.

Comment: @Servy It is an ethical principle not only for an individual but also for society: it *does* involve consequences. But this isn't the place to discuss that :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Indeed.  it's an ethical point for the society.  Most societies would consider the ethical harm of, say, killing or incriminating an innocent person to be *very* high, in this case, higher than allowing a guilty person to go free.  The harm to SO as a society when a valid vote is invalidated is *much* less than the harm done when a fradulant vote is kept.  They are both ethical questions, and the answer is different in the two contexts.

Comment: *Those quotes apply to any punishment.* @AndrewMorton - This isn't really a punishment though. What's being proposed is a limitation on certain types of voting. This is more like the rep requirements for voting.

Comment: @Servy I agree that the harm to SO and the harm to society at large *could* be seen as separate, but they are not. The people being not-naughty, yet punished for something they didn't do on SO (if this proposal was enacted and was not 100% accurate), are also people in society at large.

Comment: @AndrewMorton And the punishment is that a *very* small portion of their votes end up being reversed.  That's a *very* small amount of harm.  The harm caused by the fraud is *orders of magnitude* greater, as it means people end up being mislead by bad answers.  What's your basis for asserting that someone having a few of their votes invalidated is going to cause more harm than all of the people being mislead by poor quality answers, other than that it's your own personal opinion?

Comment: @Servy That's an interesting point. Would one person being pushed over the edge into some bad act by, what is to you and me, a trivial unqualified vote reversal be worse than possibly many people having major problems from not consulting more than one resource? Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

Comment: @AndrewMorton So you think that there will be enough people who have their votes reversed by this, that even *find out* that their votes are reversed, that then end up lashing out at the community, and end up doing more damage than all of the effects of the voting fraud that would be able to be eliminated?  I suspect that of the *very few* people that even *find out* that they had votes invalidated, very few will care, and if there even *are* any that end up lashing out at some point, they'll cause nowhere *near* the amount of harm that the voting fraud causes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The answer in no way solves the problem.  It's a *much* poorer solution than the one Brad requested, but I suspect that there are too many people like you that would rather have a worse site than have even one valid vote invalidated, and so Brad's suggestion likely won't ever be able to happen, even though it would be superior.  There simply are too few people on this site that actually care about quality content (instead being more concerned with how much rep they have) for it to ever actually happen.

Comment: @Servy Isn't question (and answer) quality a separate issue from voting fraud?

Comment: @AndrewMorton They're very much related. Voting is the means by which we measure the quality of posts; when low quality posts are fraudulently upvoted, they end up having improved visibility over the superior posts, and will end up being read first.  Additionally, the voting fraud is being used to circumvent the post ban, people doing so are doing so to post low quality content, so allowing them to continue is to allow increased low quality contributions.

Comment: @Servy I had no idea that so many despicable people were around in what should be a fairly intelligent community. Ban them! Ban them all!, I say. But how can we make sure that we only we get the bad guys when just an IP address (as per the original post) is not enough to unequivocably identify them?

Comment: @AndrewMorton They do get banned.  Often.  They just create new accounts and keep at it.  I (or rather, Brad) am not suggesting that we automatically ban all access to the site for every user that ever votes on a post from someone they share an IP with, merely that the votes themselves not count.  For a legitimate user having a vote be invalidated every once in awhile because they unintentionally voted on a post of a co-worker, or someone  using the same internet cafe, is not going to be disruptive for them, both because it will be rare, and because it's not a profound effect.

Comment: @Servy Oh, so would bans/rejections based on IPv6 addresses/subnets instead of IPv4 addresses be something the site could work towards with the increasing prevalence of the former?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Not in the short term.  In the long term, it's hard to say; we won't really know a lot of the implications until a fairly complete conversion has happened, and we're just not there yet.

Comment: @Hans I'm slightly amazed that nobody followed up on your comment. I think we all know which "part of the world" your comment addresses. I don't think we can ignore the votes of ~1/6th of the world's population.

Comment: Yes, but only if it applies retroactively. See how much rep is lost across the entire site because of this.

Comment: Anyone did any research how many votes this would affect?

Comment: @Trilarion I doubt it would be *possible* to do this.  SE is going to track your recent IP activity, but it won't have your IP history going back to forever (I suspect), so they would only ever be able to simulate this on recent votes, not going back for too long.

Comment: @SGR See previous comment.  I highly doubt the data exists to make that even possible (going back further than a few days/weeks, based on how long SE stores login info for).

Comment: @Servy A simulation/estimation is probably better than nothing. My gut feeling is that it would help to roughly know about what numbers we are talking. After a possible implementation an accurate number should be available. At least then I would like to know the number of votes invalidated. Btw. what is roughly the percentage of votes invalidated currently by other scripts?

Comment: @Trilarion They could probably simulate it going back a few weeks.  Even with a full implementation, assuming login data is only stored for a short while (a probable assumption) you would never be able to determine whether a vote cast last year was between users sharing a connection or not.

Comment: Tim's answer here might make this whole question moot: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287613/135615 , but it was still an interesting discussion to have.

Comment: @Code - yeah, everybody knows it but it is one giant taboo subject.  Gets to be pretty hard to have a discussion about it, prejudice is an ugly word.  And you just used it, it is not 1/6th.  It is far from my bed and I don't know how it ticks but it seems no coincidence that the seat of government is in the north.

Answer (score 50):

Since the primary motivation here is really about the post ban algorithm, insofar as most voting fraud appears to exist purely to subvert it, what if, rather than invalidating these votes, we simply didn't consider these votes from the post ban algorithm?  It sidesteps the highly emotional reaction that so many users have to the idea of any number of legitimate votes being reversed, while still working to address the root problem of people subverting the post ban.

This may not be *sufficient* to deal with the voting fraud that goes on, but it would likely help, particularly if the community in general just isn't willing to accept the stronger approach of actually invalidating the votes.

Comment: By itself, this is a pretty interesting suggestion. It could impact question-ban recidivism via puppets and voting rings, while not impacting much else.

Comment: @BradLarson The problem of course is that it doesn't address voting fraud not done to bypass the question ban, and also, likely more relevantly, all of the voting fraud that's going to happen by people that *think* committing voting fraud will circumvent the ban, even though it won't.  The question ban wouldn't be subverted but all of that upvoted low quality content would remain.

Comment: But they'd be stopped from posting more, so you wouldn't have a voting ring dumping dozens of bad questions on the site. If the only people giving upvotes were in their ring, and the only votes from the outside were downvotes, they'd be stopped right away. Likewise, puppets would become mostly useless. There would be little downside to this, and it could be effective even as a partial measure. It could attack part of the problem without harming much else.

Comment: @BradLarson Ineed.  My problem with my own suggestion is not that it wouldn't help, it's simply that it only solves *some* of the problems, and not others.  Personally I think that the benefits of the more significant change would be worth the side effects that come along with it, but as mentioned elsewhere, I suspect that there won't be enough support for that to happen, hence this suggestion.

Comment: I don't think this would be very problematic to do. It has the nice benefit of using a light touch while being very accurate. While it may not fix 100% of the issue, even if it gets 25% that would be significant progress. Perhaps comparing the set of users who would have circumvented the ban due to same IP voting versus not could also yield results.

Comment: Would this also apply to not considering same-IP *downvotes* for the purposes of post bans? For example, if someone posts a crappy question from a university computer lab and then someone else sits at that computer later in the day, pulls up the recent questions list, and downvotes all the crap, will our crappy question poster be shielded from a question ban because they shared an IP with the downvoter?

Comment: @RobertColumbia - I don't see why, it's not like the moderators are doing that manually now. Malicious down voting would probably still be caught by the serial voting algorithm and I don't see a way to commit fraud with down votes.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I don't think it would be *needed* to support that.  While there are abuses that one could perform (say, for example, creating tons of accounts to target someone else and try to get them post banned) this appears to be something that virtually never actually happens in practice (based on what mods have said on the topic) so the *very* rare cases of behavior like this that does happen is easily handled by manual moderator intervention.  I wouldn't strongly oppose also ignoring downvotes, but I see no reason to do it either.

Comment: @BSMP There have been a few isolated incidence of people trolling other people with downvotes/flags from rings of sock puppets, but it's *very* rare.  It takes a lot of work to set up (you need to get all of the accounts enough rep without getting cause for upvoting yourself) it's caught much more quickly than other types of voting fraud (the targeted person will get suspicious quick and flag for mod attention) and there just don't seem to be the same incentives to engage in this behavior as compared to upvoting yourself.  As a result, this behavior is rare, although it has happened before.

Comment: It is also interesting that this could help *identifying* sock puppet accounts automatically: when a user hits a question ban, a quick check of which other users up-voted several of their questions from the same IP could lead to an automatic flag being raised to moderators identifying the accounts in question (for further action).

Comment: @MatthieuM. That already happens.

Answer (score 38):

## No. This must be a manual process.

There are plenty of reasons why that is; many of them have been hashed out in the comments here. A brief selection:

- Workplaces. It's entirely possible for a set of co-workers to all have SO accounts but not know who their co-workers are on SO.. This also applies to universities or other large educational institutions; while they probably have more than *one* public IP, it's still going to be more than one person per IP.
- Shared wifi. I've had this setup before; sharing wifi with other people (perhaps in the same apartment block, or with your neighbours) means you have the same IP address. Does that mean you know your neighbour's SO account? I doubt it.
- Family. Even in the *same* household, there can be more than one person with an SO account. Again, without knowing if your family members have an SO account, it's possible to come across and vote on their posts accidentally.
- Carrier Grade NAT. This also applies to large-scale NAT installations for institutions or business. Everyone behind these systems would be potentially regarded as 'criminals' (for want of a better word) by this system, and have some of their votes invalidated without this being considered.

The moderators see a lot of bad actors coming from the same IP; it's understandable that this seems like a *lot* of people abusing the system. But the tools are there to find the *bad* actors - there's nothing you can go and find out how many *good* actors there are with.

It seems likely that there is a proportion of users - how many I don't know - who share an IP but don't know about it. The Google proxies are a good example - *lots* of people use Google proxies (VPN services, and data compression for mobile Chrome - which is used by 23.2% of people globally), and end up cross-referencing with people they don't know and will never meet. These people are still entitled to vote on everyone's posts, even if they do share an IP.

As far as I'm concerned, dealing with those who abuse the system in this way needs to be a job left to the moderators. We don't have the automated processes capable of discerning between IP-shared votes that *are* legitimate and those that *aren't* - admittedly, it's still difficult for human moderators, but I feel they do a much better job than any process could.

---

All that said, I should make it clear that I'm not *100% against* this - there are ways of tuning a system like this to make it more accurate, and to ignore or reduce the effect of some of the issues I've mentioned here. However, that takes a long time, and a lot of developer work, and I don't think it's necessary (or that SE has the time for it, at the moment).

Comment: `It seems likely that there is a proportion of users - how many I don't know - who share an IP but don't know about it. ` Yes, sure - but remember what we're proposing to do here is just limit the ability of those people to *vote for each other.* Not punish them or anything else. That's a very harmless limitation.

Comment: Uh, what are "Google proxies"? Their mobile VPN or something?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Google offers some VPN services, along with a data-saving proxy for mobile Chrome that compresses everything

Comment: @Pekka웃 Reading verbatim, "I suggest tightening this system to invalidate any votes cast between one user on an IP and another user on that same IP (using the last active IP for both at time of voting)."  This makes VPNs, CGN deployments, people on the same internet (Shared wifi), etc. all susceptible to automatic invalidation of votes.  That sounds a little overkill to me.

Comment: @ThomasWard if it weren't an active moderator suggesting this, I might suspect the same. The downsides of doing this sound minuscule compared to the potential upsides though. What's the actual harm done if colleagues, fellow students, etc. can't vote for each other?

Comment: That, @Pekka웃. It's not perfect, but I believe it'd be much more perfect than what we have now (assuming we could get it adjusted properly, which shouldn't be terribly hard).

Comment: @Pekka웃 I take your point, but I wouldn't call it a "harmless limitation" to prevent people who don't even know each other from voting for each other - just because they *might* abuse that at some point. It's like saying "you *might* get into a fight with this guy at some point, so we're going to prohibit you from talking to him at all".

Comment: The google proxies seem like they might be a way bigger deal than the other things in your list. Plenty of people use mobile chrome; I can imagine that causing a *lot* of vote invalidation, and it's basically 100% false positives, not people who have some chance of knowing each other and being biased.

Comment: @Jefromi that sounds like something that would have to be excluded from the mechanism, then - as well as that mobile Opera proxy thingy if it's still around, and any other insane proxy that has thousands or millions of customers behind it. It still doesn't invalidate the idea as a whole though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes mobile Opera is around.  You also have to take into account VPNs and proxies like PrivateInternetAccess and others that also have large user base and add an extra layer of complexity.

Comment: Mobile Chrome is currently used by 23.2% of people worldwide (source: caniuse.com stats). While not *all* of them will use data compression, I'd be willing to bet that - *among developers* - it's at least half. That's 11.6% of SO users you're potentially blocking from voting for each other. That would *have* to be compensated for somehow.

Comment: @Jefromi - Proxies are a good point, we definitely see those (mobile Opera, etc.). Perhaps a whitelist could be employed, marking known proxies and specific companies (SE is the one place that would be hit hardest by this proposal, ironically).

Comment: @BradLarson It looks like reverse DNS on the google proxies (at least for lots of them, hard to verify completeness) clearly marks them as google proxies, so it ought to be possible to whitelist them even without assuming an IP range by doing lookups on IPs seen for large numbers of users. (Or... even just suppressing it for everything like that.) Along with overall monitoring to disable this system if it suddenly starts invalidating way more votes than expected, could probably be safe enough in that regard. Still have to weigh the benefits against the losses from shared wifi etc, of course.

Comment: `This must be a manual process.` on a site with [436.567 users with the right to vote](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/586421) and, what, 12 moderators now? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @Pekka웃 21 moderators, but yeah. It already *does* work - the moderators do keep up with this with the tools they already have - this would just be an improvement.

Comment: @ArtOfCode the fact that a moderator is bringing this up (with staggering numbers) suggests that it doesn't quite work at the moment though.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - There are two aspects to dealing with voting fraud: identifying when it is happening and taking care of it when found. We have decent tools for the former, but we're not catching anywhere near all cases. And even if we do, it can be months before we identify some of them, at which point votes have been inflated for a substantial period. The larger challenge is what happens when they are found. Moderators can't invalidate votes, so we have to queue this up for SE staff, who are fewer and busier than us. This isn't scaling, so something needs to be improved in this process.

Comment: My suggestion here might be bad, but it's something that would address both detection and handling of voting fraud, and do so in a timely manner. Perhaps there are better ways to accomplish this, but I don't think that the systems and tools we have right now are able to keep up with the problem. As it is, I don't pass along invalidation requests for many voting rings I come across simply because I know that SE staff wouldn't have the time to handle them, given all the other things they're working on. There has to be a better, more scalable way to handle these.

Comment: I think that large scale proxies could easily and automatically be white-listed; simply checking the sheer numbers of users that have used the IP over the last 24 hours would set a crude but effective automatic white-list threshold. Identifying smaller scale proxies is much harder however.

Answer (score 25):

*TL;DR:* Don't use IPs as the sole criteria for auto-invalidation, but as one factor amongst others.

---

> Should the system automatically invalidate **any** vote cast by one user to another on their same IP address?

**No way**. This would affect too many legitimate users voting. As you say yourself, you don't even have any numbers, so arming this very sharp trigger just to try it out is a no-go.

Please collect some numbers on how many votes this would affect, and how many of these votes were by sock puppets/voting rings that you exposed manually with the current means. Then let us make a decision based on those facts. Maybe I'm wrong and the number of false positives would be insignificant, but I don't believe so.

I applaud your rationale, it's a good idea to do something about this and to unload the moderators and staff. But still, most bans should be reviewed manually.

> The current vote invalidation system is extremely conservative, only chasing after rapid bursts of votes.

That's true - and it also has some noticeable rate of false positives.

To relieve the burden on the moderators, I would suggest to **automate the hunting** part. Dealing with the found peculiarities should stay a manual action for some time (until you have confirmed the detection ratio and are confident in automating the sanctioning).

You've already identified some patterns that could searching for voting fraud:

- Users who vote for users with the same (or similar) name
- Users who vote for users with the same IP
- Users who vote for users which are near to a question ban
- Users who do that often in a short time
- Users who are quite new
- Users who vote for a particular (small group of) users at an abnormally high rate

Accumulate these indications (increase their weight if multiple of them apply to one vote), and once they reach a certain threshold present the case to a moderator. After some fine-tuning the rules, you'll be able to set a threshold where the votes are automatically invalidated, and another that auto-bans the users.

Comment: I pointed this out in a comment above, but identification isn't even the real problem. We have decent tools for this, and you learn to sniff out odd voting patterns after being a moderator for a while. Identification in a timely manner, maybe. A larger problem is in handling. Once we've found a 10-person voting ring, what now? We have to add it to a queue for staff to handle, and someone with database access has to sit down and review all the votes and invalidate by hand. There aren't a lot of people to do this and it takes time, so only the worst cases get passed along.

Comment: @BradLarson I guess then the voting-fraud-script that runs every night should be expanded to automatically handle that queue. Why does staff need to handle this? Why would they need to review the votes that a mod already reviewed? (OK, a second pair of eyes isn't a bad idea, and an automatic system might need to get a rollback-feature in case something with the invalidation has gone wrong).

Comment: @yellowantphil Then they create new accounts and do the same things all over again.  A handful of mods just can't keep up with that.

Comment: @Bergi - There is some discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143951/give-moderators-a-tool-to-invalidate-votes-between-users about the pluses and minuses of giving moderators a direct ability to invalidate votes. I'm not sure if a system that rubber-stamps invalidation requests by moderators provides enough oversight. Maybe with some significant restrictions and with approval from another moderator (like the current redaction tool)? That's a lot of power to hand someone.

Comment: @BradLarson I'd imagine the invalidation powers to work only on the reports generated by the automated hunting tool, not to be a free-form userid input (that's too much power indeed without rollback available to staff). The "report page" could serve as paper trail and to share opinions between the mods.

Comment: I think this was my favorite answer here thus far. Yes, **automate the hunting**. At the very least, extend the vote detection algorithm to be weekly as well as daily. Perhaps use IP address as an extra *weight*, but not as the main metric.

Comment: @TravisJ But, as Brad has already said, that *is already happening*.  The problem is that *that's not good enough*, as actually going through the process of reversing the votes, once identified, is beyond SO's capacity for handling manually.

Comment: @Servy Yes, reversing votes should get more automation (not involving staff, not requiring database access, not using a manual queue) but a) it shouldn't be based only on IP addresses and b) there still should be a manual *review* of the process. At least until it's tuned and proven to work on its own, maybe gradually for simple cases first.

Comment: @Bergi Adding a manual process at all is likely going to be a deal breaker.  Since, as Brad mentioned, the primary reason people commit voting fraud is to subvert the question ban, they'll almost always *have successfully done so* by the time the mod would be able to review the case and submit the votes for reversal, so while that would help, it wouldn't really address the core issues.

Comment: @Servy Yes, those likely would be the most easily detectable ones. An automatic banning process could be configured for them, but it needs to be *supervisable* (getting stats, viewing single decisions). It might well be fire-first, review later. I'm suggesting the review-proposed-ban-before-applying only for the first phase of testing and fine-tuning the filter. The IP-only-based one Brad wanted to enable in the OP would hopefully have shown its deficiencies in such a testing phase.

Comment: @Bergi I'm certainly not suggesting that a system be put into place without any testing or research as to its appropriateness, but saying that there be manual review during a short probationary period while the accuracy is tested is *very* different from saying that you're unwilling to remove the manual review *ever*.

Comment: @Servy Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. I didn't want to say that auto-banning is no option for the obvious cases. However, I suspect that there will always be some false-negative cases of voting fraud which moderators *want* to catch but which cannot be automatically detected *reliably* (without too many false positives), so manual review will be necessary for those. Machine learning might prove me wrong of course :-)

Comment: Best idea here. Use it as one criteria of several. For example one could only act if there are unusually many votes for each other from the same IP.

Answer (score 22):

## Yes, but apply it intelligently.

As you said, the majority of these voting rings are for

- evading question bans
- drawing attention to new questions

Add tests to check

- if the votes would lift (or avoid) a question ban
- if the rate of votes on a question or answer is above a certain threshold

This way legitimate votes from universities / NAT / Google proxy / coffee shops don't get caught in the net.

Comment: The rate threshold would probably catch universities and such, while the ban check would let people test (by attempting to vote) how close they are to a question ban.

Comment: I meant rate test the question / answer, so a bunch of votes from the same IP for the same question would get flagged.

Comment: @ssube Not sure that votes to probe a question ban is something that would happen, given that the people we are dealing with are _"the absolute laziest people I have ever seen."_

Comment: eh, I wouldn't be against universities being caught by this net. Would certainly stop students from voting on friend's posts. If the post is genuinely good other people will vote on it too, so not much is lost.

Answer (score 17):

Having been called upon to do voter invalidation from time to time, I find vote fraud to be less a binary and more a spectrum. I'm never 100% sure I'm making the right decision even with access to the full voting record. (For what it's worth, I don't see voting on my own posts; voting secrecy is sacred even for employees.) So I'm skeptical of this claim:

> Implementing this would eliminate almost all voting fraud overnight.

For one thing, we do see voting fraud between users who have no shared IPs. One particularly nasty instance is a [voting ring on Islam](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1459/138). A fraud detection system that only considered IPs would not have worked there. I'm confident I made the right call *now*, but at the time it was not an easy decision to make.

For another, it's a bit hard to separate legitimate votes from illegitimate. Take a hypothetical scenario:

> On her first week at work, a programmer runs into a tricky problem with the unusual set of tools used on her new project. Upon finding the answer on Stack Overflow, she upvotes it. Over the next few days, she upvotes other answers from the same user who seems to have a very similar development platform. She only knows the other user as a random username and avatar on the internet. One day, during a coffee break, she mentions the extremely helpful SO user to a colleague. By a twist of fate, that co-worker *is* the random avatar answering her questions!

Under an IP-based fraud detection system, these votes would be valid or invalid based entirely on how the office's network allocates IP addresses. But by my way of thinking, there's no fraud until one user seeks out posts from another user to vote upon. And even then, I'm not sure it hurts when people read through [these users' posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) upvoting as they go. (I occationally have idle [ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) arguments with myself when I organically stumble on my old answers and discover I can't vote.) Ultimately, vote fraud is most a problem when it ranks mediocre content above truly useful content. But the IP can only indicate if there's a potential conflict of interest in the voting. It can't tell us if the vote is warranted.

Finally, even assuming we could create a perfect system, I guarantee hardcore voting fraud would quickly adapt and continue as normal. It's easy to see this in the raw voting data with our existing system. Socks vote like crazy for a few days until they see their votes automatically invalidated. Then they get more conservative as they probe the system. Finally, they settle into some pattern that avoids detection. If you've been around awhile, you probably can guess what they do.

**In sum**, I think this proposal will catch a bunch of fraudulent voting in the beginning and after people adjust, will settle into a pattern of catching some naive fraud and some arguably innocent voting.

---

I'm opposed to a naive use of IP address to block voting. I think it can be a useful tool in detecting fraud, but it must be combined with other evidence to avoid invalidating legitimate votes. As designed, there are many ways to *lose* privileges, but the only reliable way to gain them is via upvotes. I don't feel comfortable statistically biasing our system against people who happen to share IPs with other programmers.

This proposal will probably have biggest impact on [regions that have exhausted their IPv4 address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion#Regional_exhaustion) and people who frequent conferences. I took a look at the two questions with abnormal voting patterns. Both were asked by people who shared an IP with at least a dozen other users in the past week. I'm fairly confident these are real people and not sock puppets. Neither question was great, but I can certainly see non-fraud-related reasons to upvote. Neither asker has a history of question bans or rate limits, either. Rather, these folks don't fully understand Stack Overflow culture.

My suggestion would be to warn users if the system suspect the voter is related to the poster in some way. Sharing an IP is one indication, but we could also key off of other indications, such as an usual rate of cross-voting. The message (which borrows from the mod message template we often send in these cases) could read something like:

> It looks like you might know this user off-site. While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the *post*, **not the person who wrote it**. This is just a reminder to please refrain from targeting specific users when voting.

Perhaps the warning could include an option to remove the vote as well.

This way, the system discourages the sort of voting that might get the OP in trouble without jumping to the conclusion that `shared IP = vote fraud`. If the user ignores enough of these warnings, we'd be justified in taking more drastic measures.

Comment: @yellowantphil: I agree. There's certainly room to improve the warning. It was just about the last thing I added to this post.

Comment: what's your take on [Servy's compromise](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338694/839601)? Per my reading idea is to discard same-IP upvotes only when checking if banned user has improved enough to unblock (as far as I know technically this is possible)

Comment: @gnat: I don't really buy the idea that these folks are mostly trying to work around q-bans. When a user's first question gets several upvotes from the same IP, it suggests people operating in a culture that differs from Stack Overflow's highly [individualistic culture](http://www.clearlycultural.com/geert-hofstede-cultural-dimensions/individualism/). That's why I prefer education (or at least an upfront warning) over quick punishment. The other problem with Servy's proposal is that there really is a problem with occasional posts getting extra upvotes for reasons outside of quality.

Comment: my understanding is Servy proposes to split and separately handle somewhat complicated tribal voting and fairly straightforward abusive voting rings made to get out of question ban. By this split system ignores (or more precisely maybe handles somehow else) your example with first question (since user didn't bump into the block yet) and intervenes only if same-IP votes go to user _after_ they were blocked (and even then, it doesn't do straightforward invalidation but only ignores these votes in calculations that determine whether user improved enough to unblock)

Comment: ...I understand that there may be cases when users need to be educated about culture differences etc but there are also cases when upvotes start piling on questions posted from blocked account coming from the same IP and in these cases it is more likely that this kind of cultural education would be a waste

Answer (score 11):

### Yes, this is probably worth doing.

- Having even an innocent vote invalidated *very very very rarely* does not do serious harm to anyone.
- If you think this can be handled manually, you're insane.

---

Voting fraud is rampant, especially in the higher-traffic tags.

Given the potential benefits, this would be worthwhile even if it's a completely stupid system that invalidates *every* incidence of cross-voting that happens, *ever* ([which is not what is being suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338675/should-the-system-invalidate-all-votes-between-two-people-on-the-same-ip/338677?noredirect=1#comment416321_338675)).

It doesn't matter that there are perfectly innocent situations where two Stack Overflow users share an IP. Imposing a limit like this is still perfectly acceptable, and easy to communicate to the user base as a relatively non-intrusive way to combat fraud.

If comments are second class citizens, then votes are arguably third class:  contributions on Stack Overflow are designed so one single vote can never decide whether it does well, or badly. Votes are crucial information *in accumulation*, but never individually.

Consequently, my losing my "right" to vote for someone else's post (or having it silently invalidated) in the very rare situation that they happen to share a network with me (because they're colleagues, or fellow students, or someone sitting next to me at Starbucks) does not do serious harm to neither me nor the person whose post I voted for, even if my vote was perfectly innocent.

Of course, mega-proxies with thousands or millions of users behind them (like apparently Google has one, according to the comments - and there's Opera Mobile) would probably have to be whitelisted, and other magic employed to decide which votes to invalidate, and which ones not to.

But given that an active moderator thinks this would be worth doing, and believes it would stop a significant portion of everyday fraud occurring, it probably is worth the effort.

Comment: I wonder about situations where a question may be of particular significance to a community for the same reason _that_ they all share an IP address. A question targeting NYU students and faculty on academia.stackexchange.com, for example, or a question about Ubuntu which arises from within Canonical HQ and gets its initial vote momentum from the same. These shouldn't be the _only_ people viewing and voting on such questions, but I don't struggle at all to imagine that some communities of experts on a subject are by their nature more likely to have IPs in common.

Comment: @JacobFord those would definitely be situations that would have to be accounted for. I think the suggestion is mainly targeted towards Stack Overflow at the moment though

Comment: Since votes are the main way of gaining reputation and privileges on the site I would hope they are considered more important then comments.

Comment: @JoeW if you're not gaining reputation if no one with your IP can vote for you, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: My point wasn't about only getting votes from people on your network but rather your comment that votes are third class citizens below comments. Since votes both positive and negative have a larger impact than comments I would say they are more important than comments.

Comment: @JoeW I would say they are less important than comments because differently from comments, they are replaceable. There's no guarantee the community will replace an important, insightful comment if it gets deleted or blocked for some reason. There's a good likelihood a vote will, though.

Comment: Votes are designed to be permanent and lasting (outside of vote fraud) while comments are designed to be purged at any time.

Comment: @JoeW It's not just about whether votes are more or less important than comments though.  It's about whether invaliding a small number of valid votes is more or less harmful than rampant voter fraud.  The fact that votes matter is exactly why it's so important to ensure that they're cast legitimately.  I'd also argue that fraudulent votes tend to do more harm than a good vote does good.  Having crap content get highly upvoted from fraud results in lots of people thinking the crap is good content, vs good content having one less upvote than it otherwise would.

Answer (score 1):

## No (not in the way described)

The impact on legitimate users could be huge. Sure, a huge portion of sock puppets, vote-rings come from the same IP but you need evidence this wouldn't hurt legitimate users.

I've seen users get hurt by a single edit rejection. Imagine what would happen if e.g. 100 users each month get votes reverted (remember SO has 6 million users or so).

You can't give them shiny points, and then take it away. (Trust me, i had a german shepherd.)

## Try alternative solutions first, and check their effectiveness

> Fewer bad questions would be asked by people now unable to evade questions bans

A good start would be increasing the voting-rights from 15 rep to 150 or so. This could make it harder:

- for voting rings to appear
- bad Q/A rising
- giving voting rights to users that don't deserve them, etc.

## If you believe you should go forth with the IP-vote restriction

Do it in a way that doesn't affect legitimate users. For example, when the algorithms indicate that those same-IP users are probably going to vote-fraud, make the voter see his +1 register, while the receiver see +0. If they don't know each other, they shouldn't complain, since they don't see anything strange. If the voter logs out he can't check total votes on the receiving question, so he doesn't see anything odd again.

Sounds like a lot of work, but it might be worth it.

Comment: I honestly don't understand all this hand-wringing over a spectacularly small number of votes in a very narrowly defined set of situations.

Comment: @Pekka웃 _"spectacularly small"_ - Are you sure?

Comment: pretty much, if you exclude mass proxies and such. Also, a comment above, from an employee, `To squash some of the concerns about coffee shops, hotels, ISP-dynamic-allocation, etc., we could implement a system that tracks how much 'churn' an IP has. If there's a high turnover of users seen at an IP, or simply a whole bunch of them with relatively little in common (think active in iOS v. PHP), this could be tuned dynamically to be less aggressive on those addresses`

Comment: @Pekka웃  If the OP proposal does have some checks, then sure. But what happens if in a Computer Science university I post a Q/A which was inspired by a commonly taught problem by a professor. A few months or years later other students would find my post, and i'd get votes reverted.  It's rare, but not sure if spectacularly rare. Or.. don't know, perhaps it is very rare, and this can be handled with a simple Meta post by the offended user.

Comment: `A few months or years later other students would find my post` they're *very* unlikely to have the same IP. Plus a limitation like this would probably have to have a time limit.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Undo is an elected moderator, not an employee.