# Asking about disallowing a friend from upvoting my posts

Tags: discussion, moderation

Last month moderators sent me a message explaining to me why they decreased my reputation. Me and my colleagues have SO accounts, sometimes we talk about each other's questions and answers, it happens that one of us upvotes a question/answer.

My questions are: is it possible to disallow my friends to up-vote my posts? Is there any way to let the moderators know that some users are from my company? Or is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you considered explaining this to your colleagues?

Comment: @Stijn My company has more then 500 employees, it's kinda hard to explain to all of them to not upvote to me.

Comment: @ziMtyth If you want your company's employees to be able to use this site, you'll all need to learn to not commit voting fraud.  If it really is a problem with lots of employees, not just a few, then your company will need to address it as a whole.

Comment: I can't understand why I get 4 downvotes, I believe that  my question is a pertinent one.

Comment: On Meta, downvotes are also used to express disagreement. People disagree with the proposal, that users from the same organization should be barred from (up)voting. You'll have to explain to your colleagues that they should not upvote each other's posts.

Comment: Change your name so nobody knows who you are. Don't reveal that name to your colleagues and they won't be able to target you for upvotes.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score 13):

No, there is no such feature. You and your colleagues/friends/classmates/relatives/sock puppets simply should refrain from voting on each others posts.

It is that simple.

Do know that there have been previous suggestions to have the system invalidate votes that are likely to come from the same organization:

[Should the system invalidate all votes between two people on the same IP address?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338675/should-the-system-invalidate-all-votes-between-two-people-on-the-same-ip-address/338775#338775)

However, nothing has been implemented yet and judging by the answers I don't have high hopes it ever will be.

Vote on content, not on people and don't go looking for users profiles to spend your votes on.

Comment: It's not as unreasonable a request as you make it sound. Colleges are quite likely to be interested in the same domains as you are. As such, if you ask a question, they're quite likely to see it. Even if they don't know that it's you specifically, there is still a better than average chance that their upvotes will go to you.

Comment: @NicolBolas yeah, I can see that happen, similar to what might happen on a niche tag where only a handful of expert users share a lot of votes between them because they value each other contributions. I think the general message is: be aware if you are in a situation where your votes or the votes you receive might be induced by more then content alone and pro-active prevent that from happening. Or something along those lines of reasoning. Is that a phrase I could/should add to my answer?